# R convert data frame to manual timeserie

Tags: r, time-series

I Have this structure in R

```
DATA = read.csv("Anomaly.csv")
DATA

   col1       col2   
 57.17339 0.00064822 
 52.90232 0.00064386 
 46.20606 0.00064144 
 61.23981 0.00064216
```

i would like a return like this

```
 col1       col2     col1-1   col2-1   col1-2    col2-2
57.17339 0.00064822   NA      NA        NA        NA
52.90232 0.00064386 57.17339 0.00064822 NA        NA
46.20606 0.00064144 52.90232 0.00064386 57.17339 0.00064822
61.23981 0.00064216 46.20606 0.00064144 52.90232 0.00064386
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try with `shift` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(DATA)`), loop through the Subset of Data.table (`lapply(.SD, ..`)`), use the`shift`specifying the`n`as 0:2.  By default the`shift`has`type` as "lag" option.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- setDT(DATA)[, unlist(lapply(.SD, shift, n = 0:2), recursive=FALSE)]
```

If we need to order the columns

```
dt[, order(sub("\\D+\\d", "", colnames(dt))), with = FALSE]
#     col11      col21    col12      col22    col13      col23
#1: 57.17339 0.00064822       NA         NA       NA         NA
#2: 52.90232 0.00064386 57.17339 0.00064822       NA         NA
#3: 46.20606 0.00064144 52.90232 0.00064386 57.17339 0.00064822
#4: 61.23981 0.00064216 46.20606 0.00064144 52.90232 0.00064386
```

---

Or `shift` can also be directly applied on the Subset of Data.table.

```
setDT(DATA)[, shift(.SD, n = 0:2)]
```

Comment: Could also do `df %>% mutate_all(funs(l1 = lag(., 1), l2 = lag(., 2)))`